# what is the mistake in this code (BST)

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

This is a method to find specific node in a binary search tree...
I don't know what's the problem, but for some reason this code isn't functioning properly.. any help?

```
public KAUstudent findNodeName(String fName, String lName){
    return findNodeName(root, fName, lName);
}

public KAUstudent findNodeName(KAUstudent p , String fName, String lName){
    if (p == null)
    return null;
    else {
    // if the data we are searching for is found at p (at the current root)
        if (fName.equalsIgnoreCase(p.getFirstName()) && lName.equalsIgnoreCase(p.getLastName()) )
            return p;
        else if ((fName.compareToIgnoreCase(p.getFirstName())< 0) || (lName.compareToIgnoreCase(p.getLastName()) <0)) 
                return findNodeName(p.getLeft(), fName, lName);
        else
                return findNodeName(p.getRight(), fName, lName);
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain what it means to not function properly. What is it doing versus what you expect?

Comment: if the the name exist in the tree, it sould return the node. else it sould return null. but sometime it return null even though the name exsit

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you don't have a proper "partial order" for your keys.  The key comparison logic needs to be something like this:

```
  when majorkey1.compareTo(majorkey2) < 0 :
      // less than
  when majorkey1.compareTo(majorkey2) == 0 AND
       minorkey1.compareTo(minorkey2) < 0 :
      // less than
  when majorkey1.compareTo(majorkey2) == 0 AND
       minorkey1.compareTo(minorkey2) == 0 :
      // equal to
  when majorkey1.compareTo(majorkey2) > 0 :
      // greater than
```

But that is NOT what your code implements.

**Update** - the corrected version is more or less correct.  (The final `else` is redundant.  Read the code carefully and think about it ... and you should be able to see why I said that.)

---

**Problem #2**:  In the code where you built the tree, you using the wrong key entirely.  You need to use the same key / key-pair and the same comparison logic when searching the tree, and when deciding where to add new nodes to the tree.

Comment: Still the same problem :/

Comment: 1) What does your corrected code look like?  2) Maybe you made the same mistake in the code that constructs the tree!

Comment: I've post an answer since we can't post long comment

Comment: But I'm reqired to do it this way (insert by ID and search by name)

Comment: That does not make sense.  A BST >>cannot<< do that.  Check your requirements again.

Comment: If the requirements really do say that, then you must search the tree exhaustively, visiting every node and testing for an exact match.  (Noting that this is >>not<< how BSTs are supposed to be used.  You would be better off putting the nodes into a simple list and iterating them ...)

Answer (score -1):

I'm guessing this is the problem

```
if (fName.equalsIgnoreCase(p.getFirstName()) && lName.equalsIgnoreCase(p.getLastName()) )
            return p;
```

it only returns p if both are true. Try changing `&&` to `||`. Since it's a BST the correct first and last names may not be in on the same level of the tree. 
You could combine first in last names into a single String and the search for that. If you want to know how to do that just comment, and I'll explain the code.

Comment: Can someone explain why this was down voted? It is a perfectly reasonable answer

Comment: I have tried this, too. And I still have the same problem :/ *every node in the BST is a record of a student  so first and last name are in the same node

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. I thought you were just inserting a list of first, and a list of last names into the tree.

Comment: Try flipping the `< 0` in the `else if` on both cases to `> 0`. I am using the same implementation as you in my BST program, and that is the only difference. This because when you reach that line it is looking to see if your search key is greater or less than the value at the node you are currently searching. If it is greater or 1 in this case, it will move left, else, it will move right

Comment: No, if it's greater or 1 it should move to right. since in BST all the node to the right of a root is bigger than it and all node to the left are smaller than it. I tried though and it didn't work too.